# Ubuntu-core on RPi3 failing login

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I've built an Ubuntu-Core image for an RPi3 but when I try to sign in with my Ubuntu-One password it responds that it can't because "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority". I'm creating the certificate exactly as the the wiki says, Ubuntu lets me log into this forum and into Ubuntu-One without any problems. But I can't get the Ubuntu-Core to log in on the RPi3. I even tried a second certificate, no luck.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Greg